# Record with foreign key constraint being removed in parent table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I have this very weird situation in my MySQL table. MySQL version 5.6. The framework I am using is Laravel 5.7 though I think it is irrelevant

So I have two tables:

1. `users` table for user information
2. `secretary_notes` table, which has a `user_id`. There is a foreign key.

```
CONSTRAINT `secretary_notes_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
```

When I tried to remove a user, it flash an error

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`incapsol`.`secretary_note_media`, CONSTRAINT `secretary_note_media_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `users` where `id` = 25851)
```

This is expected. I understand. However, the weird thing is that in my `secretary_notes` table there are record with invalid `user_id` (user being removed). When I query the following, there are lots of record.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM secretary_notes WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users AS u WHERE secretary_notes.user_id=u.id)
```

A few investigation I've done so far:

1. There is no recent modification to either of the table schema.
2. Those invalid user_id, used to be valid. I know that those users are being deleted, not some random integer that never exists

Comment: Possibly related, but typically you have an `ON DELETE ...` clause to a FK like this, but it seems to be missing here. As for the delete, are you using "Soft Deletes" on your User Model? Actually... Do you have a User model? We might need to see the code you're using the perform this delete.

Comment: Was `users` (`id`) defined: 1) As a primary key,  or 2) As a unique constraint, or 3) As a unique index/key? MySQL has some weird behaviors if the FK does not point to a PK (case #2 and case #3).